# How do I call a function based on user input in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am currently trying to create a program that learns through user input, however it converts to a string automatically.

Here's the code. I use the **shelve** module to store the commands for the code.

```
ok = {str(name):func}
asd.update(ok)
print(asd)
data["cmd"] = asd
data.close()
```

The 'asd' list contains every command which has been extracted from the shelf. I want to update it and store it, so next time it updates when calling a command.

'func' is the variable that stores the name of the function am trying to call, but string objects cannot be called.

How do I solve this?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT:
This has been solved (I totally forgot about eval() )

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If your problem has been solved, please either mark the good answer as correct, or write your own answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but from what I've understood you should have a look to `eval()`

> The eval() function evaluates the specified expression, if the expression is a legal Python statement, it will be executed.

More information [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)